# Перероблені відповіді

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Неодноразово помічав таку ситуацію, коли погана відповідь отримує мінуси, автор її значно покращує — і… нічого не змінюється.

Припускаю: тому, що ми маємо не так багато активних відвідувачів, а ймовірність того, що відвідувач помітить погану відповідь вище, ніж імовірність того, що той самий відвідувач зайде на ту саму сторінку й помітить, що відповідь переробили.

Я думаю, це може знеохочувати авторів відповідей. Але що в цьому випадку робити — я не знаю. Чи є якісь ідеї?

Приклади:

- [Max Vakulenko на «Хіба Г це [h/ɦ], а не [ɣ]?»](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/6490)
- [Mykola Prokopenko на «Як перекласти з російської слово „поделка“?»](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/6495)

Answer (score 1):

Ефективного рішення не існує.

4.5 роки тому я [запитував](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2729/2984) це саме на Політиці, і мені запропонували вибір між наступним:

1. не голосувати одразу (і забути мінуснути потім, бо маю інші заняття в житті, ніж пам'ятати про кожен неякісний допис)
2. проголосувати так, як вважаєш за потрібне, після чого не перейматися; широко це можна трактувати як «ОП вже зробив помилку і поплатився за неї; інші прийдуть і плюсонуть; один плюс перекриває п'ять мінусів, тому не варто переживати»
3. bookmark (у моєму workflow букмарки мають інше значення, а змішувати букмарковані *«цікаві дописи, слідкувати за відповідями на тему, яка особисто мене цікавить»* з *«неякісними і мало кому потрібними дописами, які треба потім undownvote»*, я не хотів би)
4. час від часу переглядати свої downvotes

Усі методи, як бачимо, мають суттєві вади. No future.

Comment: Я прихильник «1». «2» — хороша ідея, але лише коли достатньо відвідувачів, але його застосування, коли відвідувачів мало, не сприяє появі нових відвідувачів.